# Backup of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\ registry folder required

Tags: windows-registry

I am fighting to bring my Windows back to life.

Everything was completely fine with my Windows, I just tried to fix "Open with" (after right click) feature as it was not working properly, I found that the only one entry which I need to add is:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]

@="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"

when I opened regedit.exe I realized that I don't have access to this folder (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*) and also it looks like folder is empty (or I can not see because I don't have permissions, please look below), before I did any modifications I made a full backup of my whole registry (its about 500 MB and I still have it).

[please have a look, it was like this, empty * folder and I did not have permissions to go there,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcIv5.png)

After that I just tried to get access to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\ folder to add that entry, what I did:

- I opened regedit.exe with TrustedInstaller permissions, it didn't help,
- I am not sure but probably I changed the owner of whole HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT folder (I think from SYSTEM to Administrator), probably that was a mistake,
- also I tried to add the permissions for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\ folder in a safe-mode,
- also few other things which I can't remember

Anyway it did not work but it doesn't matter now, the problem is that now my system is not working properly, menu start is not opening at all, I can't change volume from tray, can't use cortana, can't see my wi-fi networks or check battery status etc, simply menu start and tray is visible but I can't use it at all, the other things in my system seems to be fine.

I think it might me helpful to import HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\ folder manually but I don't have it, I believe this folder was existing in my system but when I changed the owner of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ to get access it got lost, please look below:

[look here][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLJah.png

Could anyone upload this whole /*/ folder as I marked above? I hope it could help to fix my problem because I really tried many things to solve it, what I did to get menu start and tray back:

- tried to use windows restore point but windows said there is no recovery point available... (probably Windows is not able to see it as I always had it before)
- tried to do SFC / scannow feature,
- tried to import my whole registry backup but it was not possible, no access or something (also tried in safe-mode).
- tried to change owner of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT folder for: Administrator, SYSTEM (for full HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT folder),
- many more other things,

My system is Windows 10 Home 64-bit (2009, 19043.1415),

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect registry changes are often impossible to recover from.  You cannot use some other user's main HKEY CLASSES ROOT from another machine. That would more than likely make things worse than they are.

Two approaches:

**(A) Windows 10 Repair Install:**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the second link down and run in place. Try Keep Everything.

Because of the nature of the error here, back up important data first.

**(B) If (A) fails, Reinstall Windows:**

Back everything up, and then reinstall Windows - Windows ISO; Windows Reset (Settings, System, Back and Recovery); OR Windows 10 Media Creation Link as in (A) only use the option to Keep Nothing.